# errors: Cannot convert value of type 'Section' to expected argument type 'String' and cannot assign value of type '[string]' to 'string?'

Tags: ios, swift3

the first code is responsible for my first view controller attached in the linked picture, it runs just fine until I add the commented bit which enables user to be push to the next view whereby study units should be displayed according to the selected yearOfStudy e.g by tapping on FEEYear3 as in the pic, units of that study year under the respective course are displayed. When I uncomment, I get an error saying:" Cannot convert value of type 'Section' to expected argument type 'String' ". I should add that 'Section' under var sections is set as a struct.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, ExpandableHeaderViewDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var sections=[

        Section (courses: "Electrical Engineering",
                 yearOfStudy:["FEEYear1","FEEYear2","FEEYear3","FEEYear4","FEEYear5"],
                 expanded: false),

        Section (courses: "Civil Engineering",
                 yearOfStudy:["FCEYear1","FCEYear2","FCEYear3","FCEYear4","FCEYear5"],
                 expanded: false),


        Section (courses: "Geospatial Engineering",
                 yearOfStudy:["FGEYear1","FGEYear2","FGEYear3","FGEYear4","FGEYear5"],
                 expanded: false),

        Section (courses: "Mechanical Engineering",
                 yearOfStudy:["FMEYear1","FMEYear2","FMEYear3","FMEYear4","FMEYear5"],
                 expanded: false),

        Section (courses: "Biosystems Engineering",
                 yearOfStudy:["FBEYear1","FBEYear2","FBEYear3","FBEYear4","FBEYear5"],
                 expanded: false)
    ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return sections.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sections[section].yearOfStudy.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 44
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if (sections[indexPath.section].expanded){return 44}
        else{return 0}
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 2
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let header=ExpandableHeaderView()
        header.customInit(title: sections[section].courses, section: section, delegate: self)
        return header
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "labelCell")!
       cell.textLabel?.text = sections[indexPath.section].yearOfStudy[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func toggleSection(header: ExpandableHeaderView, section: Int) {
        sections[section].expanded = !sections[section].expanded
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        for i in 0..<sections[section].yearOfStudy.count{
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row:i,section:section)], with: .automatic)
        }
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

 /*   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let unitsVC = UnitsVC()
        unitsVC.customInit(sectionsIndex: indexPath.row, title: sections[indexPath.row])
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(unitsVC, animated: true)
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
    }
    */
}
```

[The image is for the first page of my project app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkXyz.png)

In the second code, which has the functionality of the second ViewController that displays the units of various studyYears accordingly depending on which is selected I get an error on the line written: " cell.textLabel?.text = unitsData[sectionsIndex][indexPath.row] "
which says, " cannot assign value of type '[string]' to 'string?' ". How do  I get rid of these errors?

```
import UIKit

class UnitsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    let unitsData = [
        [["fee101","fee111","fee121","fee131","fee141","fee151","fee161","fee102","fee112","fee122","fee132","fee142","fee152","fee162"],["fee201","fee221","fee231","fee241","fee251","fee261","fee271","fee281","fee202","fee222","fee232","fee242","fee252","fee262","fee272","fee282"],["fee301","fee321","fee331","fee341","fee351","fee361","fee371","fee381","fee302","fee322","fee332","fee342","fee352","fee362","fee372","fee382"],["fee401","fee411","fee421","fee431","fee441","fee451","fee471","fee481","fee402","fee412","fee422","fee432","fee442","fee452","fee472","fee482"],["fee501","fee511","fee521","fee531","fee541","fee551","fee560","fee571","fee591","fee502","fee512","fee522","fee532","fee542","fee552","fee560","fee582","fee592"]],

        [["fce101","fce131","fce161","fce163","fce165","fce181","fce103","fce132","fce162","fce164","fce166","fce182"],
         ["fce201","fce231","fce211","fce245","fce251","fce261","fce265","fce232","fce242","fce222","fce246","fce262","fce272"],
         ["fce301","fce311","fce321","fce331","fce341","fce351","fce361","fce302","fce312","fce322","fce332","fce342","fce352","fce362","fce392"],
         ["fce401","fce411","fce421","fce425","fce431","fce451","fce461","fce481","fce402","fce412","fce422","fce426","fce432","fce446","fce472"],
         ["fce581","fce511","fce525","fce531","fce545","fce571","fce564","fce590","fce512","fce526","fce532","fce572","fce552"]],

        [["fme169","fme111","fme151","fme161","fme171","fme173","fme112","fme152","fme165","fme166","fme167","fme168","fme172","fme174","fme182"],["fme201","fme211","fme251","fme261","fme271","fme281","fme291","fme202","fme212","fme222","fme244","fme252","fme262","fme272"],["fme301","fme311","fme321","fme331","fme343","fme351","fme371","fme363","fme391","fme302","fme312","fme322","fme332","fme344","fme352","fme362","fme372"],["fme411","fme431","fme432","fme452","fme471","fme472","fme492","fme401","fme421","fme422","fme441","fme442","fme461","fme462"],["fme511","fme521","fme531","fme541","fme551","fme561","fme581","fme502","fme503","fme504","fme513","fme523","fme524","fme525","fme533","fme524","fme542","fme543","fme544","fme545","fme552"]]

    ]

    var sectionsIndex: Int!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        let nib = UINib(nibName:"UnitsCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "unitsCell")

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func customInit(sectionsIndex:Int, title: String ) {

        self.sectionsIndex=sectionsIndex
        self.title=title//attribute for navigation controller bar
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return unitsData[sectionsIndex].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "unitsCell", for: indexPath) as! UnitsCell
       cell.textLabel?.text = unitsData[sectionsIndex][indexPath.row]//line with error
        return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have an array of array's. So, based on your image, lets say you want to select year 3 from Electrical Engineering.

(I'm assuming your using TableView Sections for this answer since you didn't provide additional code.)

To grab year 3, you would simply access like `let year3Data = unitsData[0][2]`

Comment: Hey, DookieMan, I have restructured the question completely...Please have a look and see if you can assist, I never quite gripped your earlier suggestion